# DIsplay information when hovering over chart - chartjs

Tags: charts, chart.js

I've created a board game website where you are supposed to guess a word and then the points are displayed on a bar chart using chartjs. Currently, when hovering over a bar, it shows the amount of points by default. What I want to do is show both the amount of points and then also a list of what words that team have guessed correctly. So, in essence, can I change the hover text on a chartjs? And if so, how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are referring to the tooltip which is showed when hovering the data elements.

You can change the data to show leveraging on tooltip callbacks, described in the doc: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-callbacks

```
plugins: {
  tooltip: {
    callbacks: {
      label: () => 'my text'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yea that seems to do the trick. I was looking at ticks earlier and not tooltip so that's why nothing was working... Thank you very much for the help, and for the swift help most of all!